# Ivy/Maven Resolve: Don't pull transitive "provided" jars

Tags: ivy, artifactory

I'm using Ivy for my projects, but we're using Artifactory as our jar repository. I actually use `<ivy:makepom>` Ant task to create a Maven `pom.xml`, so I can deploy the jars and wars back to my Maven repository via the Maven deploy:deploy workflow.

I build a big jar called `common-all.jar` that requires about 30 jars for its compilation. I specify about 10 jars, and Ivy pulls down the dependencies. As part of the compile process, I specify the log4j jar, and some JBoss jars. These jars, of course, will be provided by our environment.

With this Jar, I also a bunch of wars. I specify the `common-all.jar` as part of my dependency, and the 30 jars that `common-all.jar` requires are also pulled down. All is well and good.

The problem is when I build the war. I do not want the JBoss jars or the log4j jars included as part of the war. These will be provided by the environment. I've marked them as *provided* in the pom.xml file. when I build `common-all.jar`.

Now, the question is how do I specify that I want these when I compile the code for the war, but I don't want to include them in my war itself.

Here's a sample of my `ivy.xml` file.

How can I specify that the `common-all.jar` requires certain specific jars for compilation, but when I build it in a war, I don't want all of these jars

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info
        organisation="com.travelclick"
        module="TC-AppUtil"
        revision="4.1"
        status="release"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public"
            description="The single built artifact. Nothing else"/>

        <conf name="compile" visibility="public"
            description="The master module and transitive dependencies"/>

        <conf name="provided" visibility="public"
            description="Needed for compile. Will be provided outside or war"/>

        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public"
            description="Not required for compile, but for runtime"
            extends="compile"/>

        <conf name="default" visibility="public"
            description="The default configuration"
            extends="runtime"/>

        <conf name="test" visibility="private"
            description="Required for testing" extends="runtime"/>

    </configurations>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Normal Compile Dependencies -->

        <dependency org="ximpleware" name="vtd-xml"
            rev="2.5" conf="compile->default"/>

        <dependency org="com.travelclick" name="common-all"
            rev="4.1" conf="compile->compile,runtime"/>

        <!-- Testing -->

        <dependency org="junit"             name="junit"
            rev="4.10"                      conf="test->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Where are you retrieving the common-all.jar file from? An ivy repository or a Maven repo? The purpose behind my question is to understand the remote module configurations available

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Through my local Maven configured repository. We generate a `pom.xml` via the `<ivy:makepom>`Ant task, then use `maven deploy` to push it into the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't demonstrated how you declare the common-all dependency, so I'll make up the following example:

```
<dependency org="mygroup" name="common-all" rev="1.0" conf="compile->default;provided"/>
```

The magic is the configuration mapping:

- The local "compile" configuration is mapped to the common module and its default (compile) scope dependencies, and
- The local "provided" configuration is mapped to the common module and its provided scope dependencies.

Inside your build file the configurations are used as follows:

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path"  conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="provided.path" conf="provided"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="resolve">
        <javac ...
            <classpath>
                <path refid="compile.path"/>
                <path refid="provide.path"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>

    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="compile">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="build/lib/[artifact].[ext]" conf="runtime"/>

        <war ...
            <lib dir="build/lib"/>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I kept looking at your answer, and though. "_Dang, that's what I'm doing..._". Suddenly I saw that in your dependency `conf="compile->default;provided"` and realized. _"That's a semicolon and not a comma!_". Eight hours wasted going around and around pushing and poking here and there and wondering what I am doing wrong. You separate the configuration mappings in your `ivy.xml` with ***semicolons*** and not ***commas***. Now, I'll make that same mistake only two more times before I get it pounded into my thick skull, and I'll never make that mistake again -- until next year.

Comment: Thanks. Everything is fine now.